# Error bar ticks |--o--| don't draw for more then three conditions in dotplot

Tags: r, plot, lattice

This question is an unexpected follow-up from [Draw vertical ending of error bar line in dotplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9468150/draw-vertical-ending-of-error-bar-line-in-dotplot). While the quoted question was succesfully resolved - there is a caveat. When I introduce more then three conditions to dotplot it doesn't want to draw the vertical ticks |--o--| in the endings of error bars.

As @Josh suggested in the comments, I injected `browser()` into first line of function that draws updated `panel.Dotplot` to see what goes wrong, but it didn't come out with anything that helps me to solve it. Here is an example code for four-conditions `Dotplot()` with updated `panel.Dotplot` function that doesn't work. It will work, if you decrease number of conditions (check answer for the question quoted above):

```
require(Hmisc)
#Fake conditions
mean = c(1:18)
lo = mean-0.2
up = mean+0.2
name = c("a","b","c")
cond1 = c("A","B","C")
cond2 = c(rep("E1",9),rep("E2",9))
d = data.frame (name = rep(name,6), mean, lo, up, 
                cond1=rep(cond1,each=3,times=2), cond2)
# Create the customized panel function
mypanel.Dotplot <- function(x, y, ...) {
       panel.Dotplot(x,y,...)
       tips <- attr(x, "other")
       panel.arrows(x0 = tips[,1], y0 = y,x1 = tips[,2], 
                y1 = y,length = 0.1, unit = "native",
                angle = 90, code = 3)
}
#Draw Dotplot - `panel.Dotplot` doesn't change anything
setTrellis()
Dotplot(name ~ Cbind(mean,lo,up) | cond1 * cond2, data=d, ylab="", xlab="",col=1,
        panel = mypanel.Dotplot)
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error bars are in fact being rendered, but are not visible due to their very short length (± 0.2 units). Increasing the error to ± 1 results in the following (I've also increased the `length` specified in `panel.arrows` - i.e. the error bar cap length - to 0.5):

[image: lattice error bars]

If your true data is so precise relative to the range of x-values then you might want to consider smaller points (so they aren't as prone to obscuring the error bars) or a layout that exaggerates the x axis. For example, the following uses your original error of ± 0.2 units, and your original arrow cap `length` of 0.1:

```
Dotplot(name ~ Cbind(mean,lo,up) | cond1 * cond2, data=d, ylab="", xlab="",
  col=1, panel = mypanel.Dotplot, pch=20, cex=0.4, layout=c(1, 6), strip=FALSE,
  strip.left=strip.custom(par.strip.text=list(cex=0.75), bg=0, fg=0))
```

[image: lattice precise error bars]

Comment: Now I got the full story, cheers @jbaums! Cleveland would be proud of us ;-)